# Not able to access Firebase database in Europe while it is accessible in Asia in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have an iOS App which is using the firebase database. The App was working fine in London, UK before some days and suddenly it is not working in Europe (London,...) and working very well in Asia (India,...). We have tried to change the firebase rules to Read, Write both to 'true' for all table even though App is not able to fetch records from the database in Europe. We also have added log records (that add Start Time/End Time) in LogTable when App open and start syncing and stop syncing with the database, but I can not able to see any Entry in this logTable when Any User Install the App from European region from Apple TestFlight or From Fabric. When I try to install the Same App from Asia I can see the log's entry in LogTable also get all the sync data from firebase database.

Comment: If the app works in one location, but not in another, your security rules can't be the cause of the problem (since they are enforced on the server, and thus the same for everyone). There is currently no [known outage](https://status.firebase.google.com/), so more likely something between your location and the Firebase servers is blocking the traffic. You best way to troubleshoot is by [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_) and checking the wire traffic of the Firebase client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @FrankvanPuffelen, The app is working fine at my End (India) but not working in London, so How can I check debug logs in London without Xcode/Swift project/MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have updated the all Firebase Pods to latest then this works automatically. Seems like the issue was with firebase SDK.